# Search for words inside a csv based on a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, search, string-matching

Say that I have a dictionary csv such as:

```
fruit   vegetable   meat
banana  broccoli    beef
apple   carrot      chicken
orange  corn        pork
mango   NaN         NaN
coconut NaN         NaN
```

and another csv such as:

```
sentences
Today I ate some beef.
Corn is tasty.
I drank some coconut water.
```

I'm trying to match the strings in the sentences csv to the ones in the dictionary to categorize like:

```
sentences                   food  
Today I ate some beef.      meat 
Corn is tasty.              vegetable
I drank some coconut water. fruit
```

what would I need to do to produce that output? And should I eliminate the NaNs in order for it to work properly or can I just ignore them?

Comment: What if a sentence contains words that belong to multiple columns, how would it be categorized?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution to this as well, but for now I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do what you want. Here is a nested for loop. I am pretty sure you can perform a recursive approach or even list comprehensions.

```
fruit = ["banana","apple",...]
meat = ["beef","chicken",...]
vegetable = ["corn","brocolli"] #Nan will simply be ignored
classes = [fruit,meat,vegtable]
#Now you have your 'classes' of strings.

sentences = ["Today I ate some beef.",...]#Here are your list of sentences.
output = []
for sentence in sentences: #for each sentence
   for food_type in classes: # we check if it exists in each class
       for food in food_type: # we check each food of each class
           if food in sentence: #if that string is in the sentence we pair it into a tuple
               output.append((sentence,food_type))
```

This only matches if the string is exact (case matters). And there are caveats where wrong classes can occur such as if you have "straw" and "strawberry".

Also have a look at this [link](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-read-columns-from-a-csv-file-to-lists-in-python) to 'read' your csv to lists.